# SML/NJ - Print a list mid-execution

Tags: list, printing, sml, smlnj

I wanted to utilize the `print` function inside an SML program for sort of debugging purposes to print `integer list` type data, inside the function and during execution, e.g. inside a `let` block. However, as I saw, `print` can only print string type data. I cannot wait for the result to return to print what I want, because the function I created branches during execution and creates many different lists, and I want to see what is the resulting list at the end of each branch.

Therefore, is there a way to print a list inside of a function, as I would print a string?

Comment: `I cannot wait for the result to return to print what I want` so what do you want to do? you need to provide at least some demo code.

Comment: Perhaps I wrote it without enough clarification, but I want to be able to print the list, which I have access to, inside a function, e.g. in a `let` block

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: you need to implement the conversion from list of whatever to string, then print it. sml supports `;` so you can print it first and return whatever result you need to return.

Comment: Converting the list of any type to String is a viable solution if one could provide me with a way to do it, because I found no ready functionality for this. I imagine the functionality exists, since the SML itself does it all the time, but I found no way to do it myself. EDIT- Just saw the "implement" word. I understand it, but I wish to see if there is a ready implementation for this.

Comment: SML doesn't allow you to write overloaded code like that

Comment: The core of the question is that I want to be able to "peek" to the state of my lists during the execution of the function,by doing the right prints at the right points. Any way for that will do, including `print` or not.

Comment: @NoobDoob in this case, you can only define a function to print `integer list` but nothing else, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an `int list` you can do something like this:

```
fun printIntList ints = app (fn i => print(Int.toString i ^" ")) ints;
```

Then `printIntList [1,2,3]` will print `1 2 3`

You can do similar things for other types.

On edit: This is the best you can do with straight SML. SML/NJ has its own [extensions](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/features.html) including "access to compiler internals" and "user-customizable pretty printing" which sounds promising -- though I have little experience with their extensions to the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

Simple function for turning a list of ints into a string:

```
fun intlistToString []      = ""
  | intlistToString [x]     = Int.toString x
  | intlistToString (x::xs) = Int.toString x ^ ", " ^ intlistToString xs
```

Then you can use `print (intlistToString myList)` instead of `print myList`. It won't print the square brackets around the list, not without a little more code, but I'll leave that as an exercise because I'm lazy.